# Running my application on another machine gives me an error

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Failed to find or load the registered .Net Data Provider error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875134/c-failed-to-find-or-load-the-registered-net-data-provider-error)

My application is a C# Winforms Entity Framework/SQLite driven desktop app. (buzzwords!)

When I run the application on my machine, it works correctly without a problem. But when creating the installation package and running it on another machine, I get this errro:

> System.ArgumentException: The
>   specified store provider cannot be
>   found in the configuration, or is not
>   valid. ---> System.ArgumentException:
>   Unable to find the requested .Net
>   Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed.

How can I 'package' the data provider for SQLite? The only thing I installed on my dev machine was this: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the dupe link; that's your answer.  The data provider isn't included in any .config file, so EF can't figure out where to find the bits it needs.  You'll need to edit your application's app.config or the machine.config to add the required data provider.

Answer (score 0):

Set the sqlite reference to copy local then include it in your package